# How to open (and save) all embedded documents in a Word document?

Tags: vba, error-handling, reference, ms-word

I'm looking to write VBA to save out embedded files in a Word document.  But I'm having issues just opening them:

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim num as Integer

    Dim numObjects As Integer
    numObjects = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.count

    MsgBox numObjects  ' prints "11"

    For num = 1 To numObjects    
        If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(num).Type = 1 Then
            'it's an embedded OLE type so open it.            
            ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(num).OLEFormat.Open

            'Works for the first one but errors 5941 (the requested
            '  member of the collection does not exist) 
        End If
    Next num

End Sub
```

This code opens the first embedded file if it's not already open.  It errors on the next one.

Or, if the first file is already open, the macro just seems to do nothing.

Any hints?  (I'm doing this with Word 2010.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be quite easy- after you open first embedded file it becomes active one and next when you try to open the next embedded object you refers to active document, not to desired one. Try with object variable in this way:

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim num as Integer
    Dim AD as document
    Set AD = activedocument

    Dim numObjects As Integer
    numObjects = AD.InlineShapes.count

    MsgBox numObjects  ' prints "11"

    For num = 1 To numObjects    
        If AD.InlineShapes(num).Type = 1 Then
            'it's an embedded OLE type so open it.            
            AD.InlineShapes(num).OLEFormat.Open

        End If
    Next num

End Sub
```